# how to deploy angular-fullstack app with grunt buildcontrol:heroku command?

Tags: git, heroku, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

**When I deploying angular-fullstack app to heroku using**

**grunt buildcontrol:heroku** command, getting following warning

Warning: fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
and the repository exists.
 Use --force to continue.

I have access to repository

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution to my Question by looking into grunt build control documentation(https://github.com/robwierzbowski/grunt-build-control).

Grunt build control pushes the code to heroku remote repository using its remote URL.

In grunt file, I added remote URL instead of remote name(as below):

```
buildcontrol: {
  options: {
    dir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    commit: true,
    push: true,
    connectCommits: false,
    message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%',
  },
  staging: {
    options: {
      remote: 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp-staging.git',
      branch: 'staging',
      remoteBranch: 'master'
    }
  }
 }
```